# Add column means and row means to a matrix in r

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I have a newbie question:

```
  Example of a dataset: 
  dat = matrix(1:6,3,2) #create a dataset
 #     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    4
#[2,]    2    5
#[3,]    3    6

  rmean = rowMeans(dat)  # calculate the row means of dat
 #[1] 2.5 3.5 4.5
  cmean = colMeans(dat)  # calculate the colum means of dat
 #[1] 2 5
```

I would like a matrix as followings:

```
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]   5.5  11.5
[2,]   7.5  13.5
[3,]   9.5  15.5
```

The first row is calculated as followings:

```
  1+rowmeans(2.5) + colmeans(2) = 5.5
  4+rowmeans(2.5) + colmeans(5) = 11.5
```

This is what I tried:

```
  newdat = matrix(NA, 3,2)
  for (row in 1:nrow(dat))
    for (col in 1:ncol(dat)) {
    rmean = rowMeans(dat)
    cmean = colMeans(dat)
    newdat[row,col] = dat[row,] + rmean[row] + cmean[col]
  }
```

Any help will be appreciated and please correct my for-loop.

Comment: I see no subtraction here, the title notwithstanding

Comment: Another fairly silly option: `dat + ave(dat, col(dat)) + ave(dat, row(dat))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of functions for working with matrices in R; it's usually just a matter of finding the one you want. In this case, `sweep` is what you want:

```
sweep(sweep(dat, 1, rowMeans(dat), `+`), 2, colMeans(dat), `+`)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]  5.5 11.5
# [2,]  7.5 13.5
# [3,]  9.5 15.5
```

- The second argument is the margin, like `apply`, where 1 is rows and 2 is columns;
- the third is the vector to be operated upon across the row/column; and
- the fourth is the operation to do upon them. You need backticks around `+` to pass it as a name.

Figuring out how to arrange the functions can be a pain, but once you do, they're quite useful. Sadly the help page for some of the more complicated ones are hard to understand, but [here's some useful reading](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/library/advanced_function_r.htm#sweep) that explains a bit better.

---

Alternately, you can get a little creative and take advantage of vector recycling:

```
t(t(dat + rowMeans(dat)) + colMeans(dat))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]  5.5 11.5
# [2,]  7.5 13.5
# [3,]  9.5 15.5
```

Comment: For the "abuse recycling" way, I'd do `dat + rowMeans(dat) + colMeans(dat)[col(dat)]`

Comment: @alistaire Thanks, but if I had to use the loop (I know it is not advised in R), how would I improve my for loop? I doing something wrong can you fix it. This is purely for my own understanding. Thanks

Comment: Firstly, don't use a loop unless it's absolutely necessary. That said, you're missing some braces and need to subset `dat` by both `row` and `col` when you assign. Also, you should calculate your row and column means outside your loop, so you don't repeatedly calculate the same thing. All told: `rmean <- rowMeans(dat) ; 
cmean <- colMeans(dat) ; 
newdat <- matrix(NA, 3,2) ; 
for (row in 1:nrow(dat)){
    for (col in 1:ncol(dat)) {
        newdat[row, col] = dat[row, col] + rmean[row] + cmean[col]
    }}`

Answer (score 3):

This can be done simply taking advantage of the fact that `+` operates on matrices  element by element, without needing to use a `for` loop or `sweep`. Relies on recycling to fill the matrices with column and row means.

```
dat + matrix(rowMeans(dat),3,2) + matrix(colMeans(dat),3,2, byrow = T) 
##     [,1] [,2]
##[1,]  5.5 11.5
##[2,]  7.5 13.5
##[3,]  9.5 15.5
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for a loop. The advantage of R is using Matrix/Vector operations to do what you are trying to achieve.

```
dat = matrix(1:6,3,2) #create a dataset

rmean = rowMeans(dat)
cmean = colMeans(dat)

newdat = dat + rmean 

newdat = t(apply(newdat, 1, function(x) x + cmean))
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I had to use the loop (I know it is not advised in R), how would I improve my for loop? I doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

We can use the `row` and `col` function to do the replication

```
dat+rowMeans(dat)[row(dat)] + colMeans(dat)[col(dat)]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]  5.5 11.5
#[2,]  7.5 13.5
#[3,]  9.5 15.5
```